# React - how to check if a specific field value of an object array contains certain string?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

What should I type in XXX if I want to check if there are any object in imagesWithChangedName with id which is same as the image ID?

```
 const [imagesWithChangedName,setImagesWithChangedName] = useState([])

 const handlePhotoNameChange = (e, imageID) =>{
    e.preventDefault()
    if(imageID && e.target.value){
        if(XXX === imageID)
            setImagesWithChangedName([...imagesWithChangedName,{id:imageID, changedName: (e.target.value) }])
        }
    }
 }
```

Edit:
Also, How to replace the value of changedName value of with new value if XXX === imageID is equal to true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 const [imagesWithChangedName,setImagesWithChangedName] = useState([])

 const handlePhotoNameChange = (e, imageID) =>{
    e.preventDefault()
    if(imageID && e.target.value){
        if(imagesWithChangedName.some(image => image.id === imageID)) {
          const indexToChange = imagesWithChangedName.reduce((acc, image, i) => image.id === imageID ? i : acc, 0);
          const mutableImages = [...imagesWithChangedName];

          mutableImages[indexToChange] = { id:imageID, changedName: (e.target.value) };

          setImagesWithChangedName(mutableImages);
        }
    }
 }
```

This will find your image and replace the correct value without adding an additional value to your array.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your `if(XXX === imageID)` with:

```js
if (imagesWithChangedName.find(img => img.id === imageID))
```

To replace the content:

```js
if(imageID && e.target.value){
  const image = imagesWithChangedName.find(img => img.id === imageID);

  if (image) {
    image.changedName = e.target.value;
    setImagesWithChangedName(imagesWithChangedName);
  }
}
```